# EntityFramework Code database generation creating extra Foerign Key

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm finding that when my SQLite database is being created I'm getting an extra foreign key for a property I haven't specified.
[image]

My Entity classes and Configurations:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    // EntityFramework specific
    public ICollection<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }

}

public class EquipmentDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ComponentType ComponentType { get; set; }
    public string? Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string? Model { get; set; }
    public string? SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public DateOnly? DateOfManufacture { get; set; }

    // EntityFramework specific
    public ICollection<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }

}

public class LogEntry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public JobType JobType { get; set; }
    public string? JobTypeOther { get; set; }

    public EquipmentType EquipmentType { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateComplete { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EquipmentDetails> EquipmentDetails { get; set; }

    // EntityFramework specific
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }


}

public enum JobType
{
    Other,
    Rigging,
    Repack
}

public enum EquipmentType
{
    None,
    Skydiving,
    AircraftBailout,
    Paraglider,
    HangGlider
}

public enum ComponentType
{
    Other,
    Harness,
    ReserveParachute,
    MainParachute,
    ParagliderWing

}

public class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>

{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Customer");
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);

        builder.Property(c => c.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(c => c.LastName).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        
    }
}
    
public class EquipmentDetailsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<EquipmentDetails>

{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EquipmentDetails> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("EquipmentDetails");
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder.Property(e => e.ComponentType).HasConversion<string>().HasColumnType("TEXT").IsRequired();
        builder.Property(e => e.Manufacturer).HasColumnType("TEXT");
        builder.Property(e => e.Model).HasColumnType("TEXT");
        builder.Property(e => e.SerialNumber).HasColumnType("TEXT");
        builder.Property(e => e.DateOfManufacture).HasColumnType("TEXT");


    }
}

public class LogEntryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<LogEntry>

{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LogEntry> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("LogEntry");
        builder.HasKey(l => l.Id);

        builder.Property(l => l.JobType).HasConversion<string>().HasColumnType("TEXT").IsRequired();
        builder.Property(l => l.JobTypeOther).HasColumnType("TEXT");
        builder.Property(l => l.EquipmentType).HasConversion<string>().HasColumnType("TEXT").IsRequired();
        builder.Property(l => l.DateComplete).HasColumnType("TEXT").IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne<Customer>()
            .WithMany(c => c.LogEntries)
            .HasForeignKey(l => l.CustomerId);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming a "by convention" configuration is being automatically applied but I'm not sure what I have to do to disable it. Given I'm providing the mapping for CustomerId I can't see why it would still t ry to generate one. Anyone know?

Here's a repository if anyone is able to have a look https://github.com/steveski/Logbook

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I sjust realised that I missed the Lambda in the .HasOne call. I needed `l => l.Customer`:

```
public class LogEntryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<LogEntry>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LogEntry> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("LogEntry");
        builder.HasKey(l => l.Id);

        builder.Property(l => l.JobType).HasConversion<string>().HasColumnType("TEXT").IsRequired();
        builder.Property(l => l.JobTypeOther).HasColumnType("TEXT");
        builder.Property(l => l.EquipmentType).HasConversion<string>().HasColumnType("TEXT").IsRequired();
        builder.Property(l => l.DateComplete).HasColumnType("TEXT").IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne<Customer>(l => l.Customer)
            .WithMany(c => c.LogEntries)
            .HasForeignKey(l => l.CustomerId);
    }
}
```